# Add icon using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add font awesome icon `(<i class="icon-sun"></i>)` to input before text "subscribe".

I have

```
<input type="submit" class="newsletter-submit" value="Subscribe">
```

And I try this

```
    $('.quick_newsletter .newsletter .newsletter-submit').val(<i class="icon-sun"></i>.'Subscribe');
```

But it doesn't work. And I see only "Subscribe" without icon.

Thanks

Comment: Font Awesome doesn´t work in `value` it should be on a `class`

Comment: and generelly string has to be with quotes in javascript ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a button instead. Input fields does not allow HTML Code as Values:

```
<button type="submit" class="newsletter-submit"><i class="icon-sun"></i> Subscribe</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have jquery **mistake + wrong .val()** used. You need to use `.before()` instead of `val()`

For I.E.

```
$('.quick_newsletter .newsletter .newsletter-submit').before('<i class="icon-sun"></i>Subscribe');
```

If you still want to use **val()** , YOu can use it like

```
$('.quick_newsletter .newsletter .newsletter-submit').val('<i class="icon-sun"></i>Subscribe');
```

For more information you can check : http://www.rempixels.com/2015/04/font-icons-submit-input.html